# Stalk of $\mathcal{O}(1)_{\mathbb{P}^n}$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, projective-geometry, projective-space

Let us consider the projective space $\mathbb{P}^n$ over $\operatorname{Spec}(k)$, being $k$ a field, or even over a general ring $A$. Given a point $p\in\mathbb{P}^n$, what is the stalk of the twisted sheaf $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(1)$ at the point $p$? What is the geometric meaning of this stalk? And what happens in the case we consider the sheaf $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(-1)$? There exists any relationship between both?

Comment: Do you know that these are *locally free* sheaves?

Comment: Yes, I know they are both locally free sheaves. But I am looking for an explicit description.

Comment: What have you tried and where has it broken down (or otherwise not met your expectations)? Most books I'm familiar with give you the tools to answer this question around the time they introduce twisting sheaves - for instance, everything needed to answer your question is contained in Hartshorne section II.5 if you're working out of that text.

Comment: I know that if we take the vector bundle associated to $\mathcal{O}(1)$ which is the tautological bundle, the fibre at a point $p$, should coincide with the line quotient which defines $p$, but I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: The stalk and the fiber are different constructions. Can you clarify which one you're asking about?

Answer (score 0):

**Question:** "What is the geometric meaning of this stalk? And what happens in the case we consider the sheaf $\mathcal{O}_{P^1}(−1)$? There exists any relationship between both?"

**Answer:** If $V:=k\{e_0,e_1\}$ and $V^*:=k\{x_0,x_1\}$ by definition

$$C:=\mathbb{P}^1_k:=Proj(Sym^*_k(V^*)):=Proj(k[x_0,x_1]).$$

There is a sequence of graded $k[x_0,x_1]$-modules

$$\phi^*: k[x_0,x_1]\otimes_k V^* \rightarrow k[x_0,x_1](1)$$

where $\phi(f_0,f_1):=f_0x_0+f_1x_1$. The sheafification gives the surjection

$$(*)\text{   } \phi: \mathcal{O}_C \otimes V^* \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_C(1).$$

The prime ideal $I:=(a_1x_0-a_0x_1) \subseteq S:=k[x_0,x_1]$ corresponds to the $k$-rational point $p:=(a_0:a_1)\in C(k)$. When you take the fiber of $(*)$ at the points $p$ you get the surjection

$$\phi(p): V^* \rightarrow k\{x_0\}:=l(p)\rightarrow 0$$

defined by $\phi(p)(x_0)=x_0, \phi(x_1)=\frac{a_1}{a_0}x_0$. Dualize and you get a line $l(p)^* \subseteq V^{**} \cong V$. This gives a 1-1 correspondence between $k$-rational points $p\in C(k)$ and lines $l(p)^* \subseteq V$. Hence the tautological sequence $(*)$ is related to the fact that $C$ "parametrize lines in $V$".